# Detect number of USB controllers

Tags: windows-7, usb

Is there a way to detect thru OS the number of internal USB controllers and what connector/port is assigned to what controller when more than one controller is available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of USB controllers:

`powershell -Command "@(gwmi Win32_USBController).count"`

Assigned devices per controller (again, powershell code), but without port numbers:

`gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice | % {
    $parent = [wmi] $_.Antecedent
    $child = [wmi] $_.Dependent
    $parent.caption + '\' + $child.caption
} | sort`

Thats pretty much all the information you can get from WMI USB classes.

If you need more detail, you can either use a graphical tool like [USB Device Tree Viewer](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/usb-device-tree-viewer-download) or develop your own by modifying the C++ source code from a [sample program from Microsoft called usbview](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/USBView-sample-application-e3241039).